# Input value in an empty string in a column

Tags: r

I need to replace the empty parts of a column with an alphabet ("S").

```
titanic3$embarked  <- as.character(titanic3$embarked)
> str(titanic3)
titanic3$embarked[is.na(titanic3$embarked)]  <- "S"
> t1  <- select(titanic3, embarked)
> View(t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `which` function. My example:

```
# Create data frame with two columns: value and value2. The last has 2 NA values
df <- data.frame("value"= c(1, 3, 5, 7), "value2" = c("A", "B", NA, NA)) 
# Convert column to character
df$value2 <- as.character(df$value2)
# Find which value in column is NA and replace it with "S"  
df$value2[which(is.na(df$value2))] <- "S"
```

And otuput

```
> df
  value value2
1     1      A
2     3      B
3     5      S
4     7      S
```